# vue.js: how to escape variable in escaped content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm using vue2 and I need to escape a variable inside escaped content.
Sounds strange, but this code will clarify (table cell inside a row):

```
<tr v-for="(site, siteIndex) in mySites" :key="siteIndex">
    <td>
      <b-tag>
         {{ myStatusObject.{{ site }}.someString }}
      </b-tag>
    </td> 
    ...
```

I need to escape the `site` variable inside the escaped content.

How do I do that ?

The standard documentation only covers simple cases, this seems to be more advanced and maybe not (yet) possible in vue2 ?

Please help :)

P.S.: Using things like

```
{{ myStatusObject[site].someString }}
```

doesn't work. I **need** to escape `site`.

My myStatusObject looks like this:

```
{
  abc: { someString: "test1" },
  def: { someString: "test2" }, ...
}
```

where "abc" and "def" are the sites. Calling 
`myStatusObject[site].someString` doesn't work.
I should be able to access the site object by escaping without the need of a second for loop.

If I hardcode `{{ myStatusObject.abc.someString }}` for testing purposes everything is fine.

Comment: The question I have is why do you need the logic for ```{{ myStatusObject.{{ site }}.someString }}```? What is the value that you want to represent?

Comment: The site variable gives me the right key in myStatusObject, by which I can get the value of someString

Comment: Have you considered calling a method that will do this for you? Thus eliminating the case for escaping?

Comment: Yes, but I tried to avoid that. I thought this should be possible in vue2, but maybe I am wrong...
This would be a nice feature request for vue3 :)

Comment: What do you mean by *escape*? What type of escaping do you need (there are several)? On the face of it `{{ myStatusObject[site].someString }}` seems to be what you're asking for, could you maybe explain why that doesn't work?

Comment: @skirtle: I added some information to my original post.

Comment: I've tried to put together a Fiddle that does what you're trying to do. It works fine so perhaps you could create one of your own that allows us to see the problem you're having? https://jsfiddle.net/skirtle/d12erhug/4/ My guess at this stage is that `mySites` is not an array of strings like it is in my example.

Comment: `myStatusObject[site].someString` is *definitely* the solution here. Is it not working perhaps because there is a site that does not exist in the object, which would cause the `.someString` access on `undefined` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this syntax `{{ myStatusObject[site].someString }}` it's works fine, I think you've an issue with `bootstrap-vue` config :

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {

      sites: ["abc", "def"],
      myStatusObject: {
        abc: {
          someString: "test1"
        },
        def: {
          someString: "test2"
        },

      }
    };

  }

});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>>



<div id="app" class="container">

  <table class="table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(site,index) in sites">
        <td>
          <b-tag>
            {{ myStatusObject[site].someString }}
          </b-tag>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into my post, this was one of my first ideas...doesn't work. :)

Comment: Hi, I think this might be a problem with async data. I'm running multiple axios calls via a for loop (for each site), triggert by an event via EventBus (-> mounted). This is a very complex scenario and somehow my data object isn't always complete. I'm setting this issue to solved, because this is an issue of axios in for loops. :)